# Ubuntu 16.04 refuses to install

Tags: system-installation, 16.04

I am attempting to install Ubuntu onto my laptop that is running windows 10. I have installed the .iso to my flash drive, and I allocated more than enough space for it. Whenever I select the flash drive, instead of running the installer, it then goes to grub rescue and I have to restart my laptop. Thanks in advance!
Extra: I mounted it with Unetbootin

Comment: What program did you use to burn the ISO to the flash drive? A lot of times it saves time & frustration if you just burn it to a blank DVD.

Comment: @AndroidDev I used Unetbootin to mount it. I don't own a blank DVD sadly enough and I live way out of town so running to the store isn't something I want to do.

Comment: Try this alternative: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

Comment: Do you have a pen-drive/USB

Comment: I'll add as an answer. Would you mind to mark as such?

Comment: @Android Dev yea I did, one more thing though. I made an empty partition for it but when I try to select it for the download it says " no root file system is defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu"

Comment: So are you saying that the program didn't work?

Comment: @Android Dev no it did work, I am in Ubuntu. But when I try to actually install it to the place that I emptied for it it gives me the error I listed above.

Comment: Okay, since AU is a Q&A site and not a forum, what I would ask you to do is post as another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this alternative program: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/